# How can I pick a one array out of 400?

Tags: ios, nsarray

I have a file with 420 NSArrays of words. Each array has between 10 and 200 NSStrings. The file size is 988 KB.

It builds and runs fine when the compiler does no optimization. But when I try to make an archive it hangs at "Analyzing 86 of 86 files." I suspect it's because the compiler gets stuck on optimizing the file. I split the file into two parts and it will archive after about an hour of compiling.

I put the arrays into a dictionary and then return just the one array that I want. I think that's what's hanging up the compiler.

```
-- 420 NSArrays ...
NSArray *foils_easy = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:a_easy, about_easy, ... you_easy, your_easy, nil];

NSArray *keys = @[@"a", @"about", ... @"you", @"your"];

NSDictionary *allFoils = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:foils_easy forKeys:keys];
return [allFoils objectForKey:target];
```

I don't really need the dictionary, except to determine which array to return. Is there a way to construct the array name so that it can be returned? Maybe something like you can use in putting an image on the screen?

```
NSString *foregroundImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ForegroundL1", scene];
```

I really didn't want to put in 420 'if' statements so I'm hoping there's a better solution.

Comment: You should have all this stuff in a plist or JSON file.

Answer (score 5):

You should try putting the word arrays into a plist file and loading it at runtime, rather than including all of these string literals. That will keep your code cleaner, and probably resolve this issue.

Comment: A plist is basically just a specially formatted XML file. Take a look at the NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: method, as well as the plist programming guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i

Comment: Actually, JSON is probably a better choice -- more concise and easier to code, especially with nested structures.

Comment: Ya JSON isn't a bad choice either, Plists were just historically the "iOS way" to do it, but you can easily read in a json text file and parse it.

Comment: And also, if you do use Plists, you can use the Xcode plist editor instead of writing XML by hand.